# Assign a string created in a function to a typedef structure array created in main

Tags: c, arrays, pass-by-reference, typedef

Alright.  So I have this program in C where I take a string with arguments and values (Such as: "GO 45 STOP 15").  The goal is to parse the string and place the argument with its corresponding value into a typedef structure to work with later on.

This is what my structure looks like:

```
typedef struct {
    char* keyword;
    double value;
} parameter;
```

Here are some copies of my code that I am having issues with.
Both main() and initParams() are in the same file and therefore both have access to the same #defines...

main():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "findArgs.h"

#define STR0_SIZE 80
#define LIST_SIZE   4
#define MAX_PARAMS 15

void main(){
int i;

char str0[STR0_SIZE] = "LEFT 45 GO 686 GO 34.3 STOP 56 RIGHT 26";   //Input String
char* wordList[LIST_SIZE]={"GO", "STOP", "LEFT", "RIGHT"};

int num_arg = 0; //Number of arguements in str0 (each space denotes the end of an arg)

parameter* param;
initParams(param);

replaceSpaces(str0, &num_arg);

findWords(param, str0, num_arg);
}
```

initParams:

```
void initParams(parameter* param){
int ctr0, ctr1;

param = (parameter*) malloc(MAX_PARAMS * sizeof(parameter));
printf("\n%i\n", sizeof(parameter));
for(ctr0=0;ctr0<MAX_PARAMS;ctr0++){
        param[ctr0].keyword = "";
        param[ctr0].value = 0;
}
```

}
ok some quick explainations.  initParams is for allocating the memory for each of my parameters.  I am assuming that I will not have any idea how many parameters will be included in the string and plan on determining the number in the string later in the program.  I do know that I will not accept more than parameters in the string.
After allocating the memory, I loop through each one and initialize each value to either an empty string or 0.  (I do realize this is probably unnecessary, however I have done this as part of my code troubleshooting.

Continuing on, replaceSpaces() simply loops through the string and replaces each occurrence of ' ' with a '\0'.  It also counts the number of arguements present in the string so that I know how many new strings I have just created by adding null terminators.

Now the tricky part in which I am having difficulty.

```
#define MAX_ARG_LENGTH 20

void findWords(parameter* param, char* str0, int num_arg){
parameter temp[countWords(str0, num_arg)];
int i;
int ctr0,ctr1, ctr2=0;
int word=0; //flag
char tempStr[MAX_ARG_LENGTH]="";
char* c0 = str0;

for(ctr0=0; ctr0<num_arg; ctr0++){
    word=0;
    ctr1=0;
    if(((*c0 > 'a') && (*c0 <'z')) || ((*c0 > 'A') && (*c0 <'Z'))){
        word=1;
        tempStr[ctr1]=*c0;
        ctr1++;
    }
    while(*c0 != '\0'){
        c0++;
        if(word)
            tempStr[ctr1++] = *c0;
        printf("\ntempStr: '%s'\n", tempStr);
    }
    if(word){
        param[ctr2].keyword = tempStr;
        printf("%s\n", param[ctr2].keyword);
        ctr2++;
    }
    c0++;
}
    for(i=0; i<num_arg/2;i++){
        printf("'%s'\n", param[i].keyword);
        printf("'%g'\n", param[i].value);
}


}
```

This function works properly at finding each word in the string and storing it in tempStr.  My issue is with assigning it to my parameter array back in my main().  I have tried assigning them to a temp array of parameters and then setting "param" equal to the temp array.  However due to the fact that param is a pointer, when I assign it a local location, after the function is finished, the memory is freed and lost.  Enter my idea to use malloc to predefine memory for them and assign it after.

This is my current output when I compile and run the code.  I added comments to clarify

> 16   //sizeof(parameter)
>
> 5    //Number of words in str0
>
> LEFT
>
> GO
>
> GO
>
> STOP
>
> RIGHT
>
> 'RIGHT'   //Things in single quotes are prints from the array of parameters
>
> '8.05316e-315'
>
> 'RIGHT'
>
> '0'
>
> 'RIGHT'
>
> '8.04051e-315'
>
> 'RIGHT'
>
> '0'
>
> 'RIGHT'
>
> '0'
>
> MAIN:   //I printed these in main using the same for loop seen in findWord()
>
> '▒▒'
>
> '8.05316e-315'
>
> '▒▒'
>
> '0'
>
> '▒▒'
>
> '8.04051e-315'
>
> '▒▒'
>
> '0'
>
> '▒▒'
>
> '0'

If anyone can help me properly assign the contents of tempStr to a parameter in my array declared in main I would be greatly appreciative.  Please Let me know if you need any more information.

THANK YOU ALL!!  I GOT IT!!!

Rather than make "tempStr"  I just assgned the characters directly to the param[index].keyword.  It worked like a charm

Thank you guys very much!  I had read many different Qs and As here before but this was my first time posting.  I am very excited with how quickly you guys were able to reply.

Thanks again!

~Nick

Comment: "Please let me know if you need any more information" More information? Less information would be quite welcome :) In fact, a short, self-contained example would be ideal.

Comment: `parameter temp[countWords(str0, num_arg)];` this shouldnt compile.., perhaps removed because it is unused anyway..

Comment: Yes I do realize it is a lot  D:  but I didnt feel that I could convey the issue without throroughly explaining my set up.

Comment: also countWords() returns an Int so all I am doing is calling "parameter temp[AN_INT_HERE];" and declaring the temp array

Comment: You are not allowed to declare an array with a size that is not a compile time constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what `param[ctr2].keyword = tempStr;` does It does not copy the string in `tempstr` to `keyword` it just makes `keyword` point to `tempstr`, which means all the keywords will point to the `tempStr` variable and will be invalid if you access it outside this function.

What you want to do is to make

```
char* keyword;
```

into

```
char keyword[MAX_ARG_LENGTH];
```

And use something like `strcpy` or `strncpy` to do the copying.

You also do not appear to be setting `value` anywhere

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.
If I were to go about copying the string into `param[ctr2].keyword` is there a simplier method than copying char by char.  I am trying to avoid using the prebuild string functions such as strcpy and etc...  I have no problem writing my own string copy function, I was just requested by my mentor to not use the prebuilt string functions.

Comment: well.. u could write a `mystrcpy` function which does the char by char copy and use it everywhere.

Comment: Or you could try memcpy.. but you need to be careful of length of string to copy etc

Comment: Thank you guys! no need to copy the string when I can just put it where it belongs in the first place.  ;)
Thanks for the Help!